# php preg_match and regex regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to use the regex:

```
/(.*)[.\s][sS](\d{1,20})[eE](\d{1,100}).*/i
```

to filter for the title of a tv series. (e.g. The Big Bang Theory S04E05) In order to remove the episode string (S04E05).

I've tested my regex with http://www.phpliveregex.com/ and everything works fine. But including it to my website, I'll get the whole title including the episode string.
The return value of preg_match is 0.

My Code:

```
$ret=preg_match("/(.*)[.\s][sS](\d{1,20})[eE](\d{1,100}).*/i", $title,$output);
if($ret==1){
    $title_without=$output[1];
}
```

Comment: show exactly what's in `$title`, then. we can't help you fix a regex if we can't see what you're feeding into it.

Comment: I think something like this: (e.g. The Big Bang Theory S04E05)

Comment: $title="The Big Bang Theory S04E24"

Comment: Using http://www.phpliveregex.com/ you see the first element of array is the whole string... did you test 2nd element of array... ?

Comment: Yes I do so... But the return value is still 0. I believe there will be no accordance

Comment: It doesn't return 0 if what you've told us the title is is actually what's being matched against. See https://3v4l.org/4kT58.

Comment: just that's my problem ... When testing it, everything works and I get the return value 1, but on the website it does not ... It makes no sense to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inside a double-quoted string, you need to use double backslash to escape regex shorthand classes.

You can use your regex inside a `preg_replace` function inside *single quotes* so that you do not have to double backslashes:

```
$title= "The Big Bang Theory S04E05";
$ret=preg_replace('/^(.*)[.\s]s\d{1,20}e\d{1,100}(.*)/i', '\1\2', $title);
echo $ret;
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/r125ig). Result: `The Big Bang Theory`.

The back-references `\1\2` will restore the substrings before and after the episode substring.

Since you are using `/i` modifier, you need not use `[eE]` or `[Ss]`, just use single letters in any case.

To return the substring before the episode and the episode substring itself, just use the capturing groups with `preg_match` like here:

```
$title= "The Big Bang Theory S04E05";
$ret=preg_match('/^(.*)[.\s](s\d{1,20}e\d{1,100})/i', $title, $match);
echo $match[1] . PHP_EOL; // => The Big Bang Theory
echo $match[2];           // => S04E05
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/u1FI9E)

Comment: Is it possible to get the episode string as well?

Comment: The problem with your regex is stated at the beginning of my answer. You used double quotes for regex declaration, thus, backslashes with classes like `\s` must be doubled. When using single quotes, you do not have to double backslashes as a ``\`` then is treated as a literal backslash. Also, I suggest using capturing groups so that we can access the details we are interested in.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, if you do not care about how many digits there are after `s` or `e`, you may just as well use `\d+`, no need in the limiting quantifier `\d{min, max}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for words and match all but the last one:

```
$matches = array();
$regex = "/^([\w ]*) [\w]+$/i";
$title = "The Big Bang Theory S04E05";
preg_match_all ($regex, $title, $matches);
```

Now all your matches are in `$matches`.